# Permissions error trying to run Appium test on Android

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, appium, mobile-automation, android-automation

I am not able to run my automation testing with Appium server using Eclipse with Selenium. The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. 
java.lang.SecurityException: You need the android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS permission to use the PackageManager.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS
```

The code I am trying to run is:

```
package tests;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class StartChrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Set the Desired Capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "My Phone");
        caps.setCapability("udid", "7970dc54"); // Give Device ID of your mobile phone
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "9 PKQ1.180904.001");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.vending");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity");
        caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");

        // Instantiate Appium Driver
        try {

            AppiumDriver<MobileElement> Driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(
                    new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What setup steps have you followed on the phone?  Is USB debugging enabled in developer options?  Is the phone connected to the computer in file transfer mode (not charging mode)?

Comment: Hi Rhaul, I've placed this on hold for now. Could you make this post less like a debug report and more like "Here's what I tried to do, here's what I expected to happen, here's how I tried to fix it, etc."

Comment: @anonygoose yes USB debugging enabled in developer options, and also my phone was connected to the computer in as file transfer mode(not charging mode)....but i still unable to run this program  please check below:

Comment: Hi @corsiKa i am using first time this site thats why dont know much more about that by the way i have edited my Problems once again please let me know and check if you need any kind of information further...please help me asap

Comment: @c32hedge i have edited my problem please check now and let me what should i have to do......

Comment: @RahulKumar The culture at StackExchange sites seems such that you search (e.g. 30 min) for an answer (your favorite web search engine) before posting. And each question is for a specific problem (so that when someone else finds this question, they also get a solution, but not unrelated information). And if you get that problems solved and your thing is working and you get *a new* (probably unrelated problem) then you make a new question. *Ideally* when joining a new community one should to read the rules (not many do). I recommend at least looking around to see how people have been behaving.

Comment: I don't have security debugging option in developer mode Under realme 1... Is der any solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem lies with the errors:

> java.lang.SecurityException: You need the android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS permission to use the PackageManager.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS

This is saying that the phone does not have permission to run your software.

Because your code is setting the capability `"noReset"` to `true`, you can't set the capability `"autoGrantPermissions"` to `true` because it won't work. The two capability settings are incompatible.

This limits your options.

You could remove the `"noReset"` capability, if it is not essential that your device keeps the app running and the app data in local memory. That would then allow you to set `"autoGrantPermissions"` to `'true'` and probably fix your problem. (http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/reset-strategies/index.html has more information)

You could specifically install the permissions using adb - there is a Stack Overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410167/how-do-i-use-adb-grant-or-adb-revoke) with more information. You should do this with your code, so you don't leave the device with an open security flaw.

You could probably also use the [Java Appium API](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.appium/java-client/7.2.0) call from the package `io.appium.java_client.android.appmanagement` and the class `AndroidInstallApplicationOptions` `myInstallOptions.withGrantPermissionsEnabled()` which will grant all required permissions as soon as your code is installed.

I'd also suggest you take some time to review the Appium [documentation](http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/intro/).

Comment: Hi @Kate Paulk, thanks for the help... its working now i am very happy. but after sometime app got automatic disappear and in my Eclipse i have found this error again: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
 at io.appium.java_client.HasSessionDetails.lambda$0(HasSessionDetails.java:52)

Comment: @RahulKumar - NoClassDefFoundError usually means that the class it's referring to (org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils) is not in the Java classpath. You will need to configure this class to be included in the package you send to be run. https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html has a decent description of how to resolve the problem if you read far enough down the page

Comment: Hi @Kate Paulk, now i add that in java class path. Thanks a lot for this. I want to inform you that now i got no any error but still after sometime app got close automatically. I want to know why this happened? is this any kind of error? Now in my eclipse console its showing: Sep 24, 2019 10:44:38 AM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

Comment: @RahulKumar - what your console is showing is normal. The app closing after a time would most likely be normal cleanup.

Comment: ok sir, i understood and now i am facing the issue with uiautomatorviewer also when i tried to run its give error : -djava.ext.dirs=..\lib\x86_64;..\lib is not supported. use -classpath instead. I think this is beacuse java version 12.0.2 is not suppprting this so can you give me some alternate for this, i dont want to install java 8.1 again and do setup. i need solution at this point of my work, please help me this also

Comment: @RahulKumar - I suggest you try searching for answers - I needed a few tries before I found the last answer to this Stack Overflow question which should fix your issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506036/uiautomatorviewer-error-could-not-create-the-java-virtual-machine?noredirect=1&lq=1 The issues you are having are basic "how to run Java" issues, so SO should have what you need.

Comment: Hi, can you see this issue also, urgent: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/42855/41592

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution that helped me:

- enable USB debugging, in USB debugging (Security settings)
- Install via USB options in the device you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this , I had my Sim inserted and Developer Options -> USB debugging (Security settings) and USB Debugging- Both Turned ON but in my device i was still facing the same issue then i activated : Install Via USB - Turned ON. Now Its working fine i guess my REDMI device had this additional option other phone might not have.

This webpage has all related capabilities for running Appium : http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/index.html In my capabilities section i also added 2 new capabilities for Actual device saying:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap= new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");
cap.setCapability("enforceAppInstall", "true");
```