# I have been struggling for more that a day to fix the Duplicate class given when running my android project for automation

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, appium, quality-assurance, android-automation

> Error: Duplicate class org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext found in modules jetified-java-client-7.3.0.jar (java-client-7.3.0.jar) and jetified-selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar (selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar)

**Please check my code in android studio for automation with selenium jar and aapium**

```
package com.example.babilok;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class MainActivity {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Set the Desired Capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Redmi");
        caps.setCapability("udid", "e6c7eed472e00d89"); // Give Device ID of your mobile phone
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "9 PKQ1.190319.001");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.example.babilok");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.example.babilok.MainActivity");
        caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");

        // Instantiate Appium Driver
        try {

            AppiumDriver<MobileElement> Driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),
                    caps);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Please check my android all jar files that i embed in image]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Your code looks okey. please share the error in comments to check the details

Comment: Hi @GregBurghardt please check error as below:   Duplicate class org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext found in modules jetified-java-client-7.3.0.jar (java-client-7.3.0.jar) and jetified-selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar (selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar)

Comment: Hi @HemantVarhekar please check my above comment for error

Comment: Please edit your question and add this information. It gets lost in comments too easily.

Comment: @GregBurghardt please check now error, and guide me ASAP. I am stuck on on it, I have tried multiple way to get answer but no solution. Help me

Comment: @HemantVarhekar, please check my edited question now with error mention.

Comment: Hi @GregBurghardt, please check now

Comment: @GregBurghardt check my issue please

Comment: @HemantVarhekar look into my issue please

Comment: @RahulKumar I am having the same issue for the past 2 days. It appears that its not as easy as some exclude lines in the app's gradle file either. Did you ever find a way to get it working?